# VSCode Glean extension error -4094 - what does it mean?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, system-calls, vscode-extensions

I'm running the [`wix/vscode-glean`](https://github.com/wix/vscode-glean) VSCode extension on Windows 10 and hitting this issue when trying to extract react component.

```
[2018-11-03 19:51:26.898] [renderer1] [error] [{"errno":-4094,"code":"UNKNOWN","syscall":"stat","path":"\\\\d:\\multivariate-hypergeo\\src\\PopulationInput.js"}]
[2018-11-03 19:51:26.913] [renderer1] [error] [{"fileOperationResult":1,"options":{"acceptTextOnly":true}}]
[2018-11-03 19:51:26.930] [renderer1] [error] [{"fileOperationResult":1,"options":{"acceptTextOnly":true}}]
```

My only guess is that this was written with only linux in mind, and the syscall `'stat'` doesn't mean anything (or the same thing) on windows?

I've raised [an issue](https://github.com/wix/vscode-glean/issues/36) but I actually want to understand the underlying issue.

What does the error message

```
{"errno":-4094,"code":"UNKNOWN","syscall":"stat","path":"\\\\d:\\multivariate-hypergeo\\src\\PopulationInput.js"}
```

mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension was patched to work on Windows 10, via [these two commits](https://github.com/wix/vscode-glean/compare/a07eb2e...96f875c).

`(vscode.)Uri.Parse` becomes `Uri.file`, for instance:

```
edit.replace(vscode.Uri.parse(`file://${path}`), new vscode.Range(start, end), text);
```

became

```
 edit.replace(Uri.file(path), new vscode.Range(start, end), text);
```

So it should now for for version above 4.2.2